# Overview in Subsection or Before Subsection

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I am writing a technical document with a large chapter describing work completed. Before describing each task I would like to have a brief summary of the tasks. Is it considered more proper to have a `\subsection` for the summary or to put the summary in the space between the `\section` and first `\subsection` describing the tasks?

That is, is it better to do this:

```
\section{Work Completed}
\subsection{Summary}
We completed task 1, task 2, and task 3.
\subsection{Task 1}
Describe task 1
\subsection{Task 2}
Describe task 2, and so on
```

or this:

```
\section{Work Completed}
% \subsection{Summary}
We completed task 1, task 2, and task 3.
\subsection{Task 1}
Describe task 1
\subsection{Task 2}
Describe task 2, and so on
```

Comment: I tend towards the second option -- that way the subheadings convey useful information. The purpose of an introduction/overview for the section is obvious without a subheading.  It also saves on page space which may be handy if you're fitting in a lot of large figures (big chunks of space such as those around headings can make end up pushing figures further into the document).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the first section contains this

```
\section{Work Completed}
```

and nothing else. Everything else belongs to the second section.

```
\section{Summary}
We completed task 1, task 2, and task 3.
\subsection{Task 1}
Describe task 1
\subsection{Task 2}
Describe task 2, and so on
```

This makes no sense. So certainly the second option is better than the first.

```
\section{Work Completed}
We completed task 1, task 2, and task 3.
\subsection{Task 1}
Describe task 1
\subsection{Task 2}
Describe task 2, and so on
```

Here, everything is included in a single section and there is no empty section first. So this makes sense. The other option would be to do something like

```
\section{Work Completed}
\subsection{Summary}
We completed task 1, task 2, and task 3.
\subsection{Task 1}
Describe task 1
\subsection{Task 2}
Describe task 2, and so on
```

I don't think there is much point in this and I wouldn't do it, but it makes equal sense logically. Depending on your document class etc., you might also be able to do something like

```
\section{Work Completed}
{\renewcommand*\abstractname{Summary}%
\begin{abstract}
  We completed task 1, task 2, and task 3.
\end{abstract}}
\subsection{Task 1}
Describe task 1
\subsection{Task 2}
Describe task 2, and so on
```

However, as you didn't provide a minimal example, it isn't possible to know if this would work in your case or not. In any case, it is not necessarily wise. In most cases, just putting the summary where it goes is probably the best option.

Comment: You are correct. This is actually a typo in the first example. It should actually be `\subsection{Summary}`